# Increasing memory to avoid OutOfMemory error

Tags: java, eclipse, excel

I am getting an OutOfMemoryError using Apache POI. I am extracting over 400,000 records from the data base to an excel sheet. Currently my eclipse.ini file looks like:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

I know I have to increase my memory but I am not sure how much should I change it too. Also should I be changing it in other places too? I'm sure there are links about this so if someone could direct me, that would be great.
Thanks in advance,
Sonny

Comment: I'd be more inclined to change the way the way you write your data to an excel file. 400 000 records aren't that many. Have you taken a look at SXSSF?

Comment: Blindly adding more memory is not a scalable solution. What will you do when the amount of memory you need exceeds the amount your motherboard supports?

Comment: it depends on how big is the record, I guess. you should increase memory in run configuration, not in eclipse.ini file.

Comment: @SimonVerhoeven I have not taken a look at SXSSF. Right now I am using XSSF. Is there a big difference?

Comment: @Renan what do you suggest? I have removed all of the formatting of the cells. I had disabled autocolumnsize to cut down on execution time. It just runs out of memory when writing to the actual excel file

Comment: @chetan what setting should I put in the run configurations? Thanks

Comment: It is a streaming variant, so you can't edit the excel rows later on. But if you're just transcribing data, or have no need to access the rows later on it is a lot more memory efficient.

Comment: @Sonny check how much memory you need to write 1 row. Then 10. Then 100. Once you find a reasonable limit, say `N` rows... Change your code to write `N` rows, then stop, then write the next `N` rows (rince and repeat). Just don't try to write them all in one single round. This way you can limit the amount of memory your application will use. Have a +1, and good luck and happy coding ;)

Comment: If you are really sure that you are not creating unnecessary objects then try changing JVM args -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m depending on your error

Comment: @Renan Thanks Renan for this suggestion. Sorry to ask you this but I am a relatively new programmer. What is the best way to check the memory needed per record? How would I be able to trace this?

Comment: Memory profiler, or trail and error. But I would suggest improving your code first before increasing memory.

Comment: I am going to look into my code because when I made the memory changes recommended I now get a GC out of memory error. I think I may have a leak

Comment: @SimonVerhoeven  Hello Simon I used SXSSF and it worked perfectly. It extracts the 400,000 plus records in 2 minutes. Thanks for your help. And Thank you everyone on this post for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has a maximum number of rows.  For **XLS** the limit is **65536** rows and for **XLSX** the limit is **1048576** rows.  So as suggested you could use SXSSF or write it out to csv.  As for changing the heap size there are a few ways to do this.

1. change the -Xmx512m in the eclipse.ini to -Xmx1024m (1GB) or whatever you would like.
2. In Eclipse go to Run Configurations >> Aruguments and under VM arguments put -Xmx1024m
3. If you have a Plug-in project with a product you can go to the Product select the Launching tab and under the VM Arguments: put -Xmx1024m